# Find all loaded files in website to create ApplicationCache manifest

Tags: javascript, html5-appcache, arcgis-js-api, js-amd, application-cache

I'm trying to figure out a way to automatically generate an ApplicationCache manifest file from all the HTML,CSS,JavaScript and images files used by our website.

We need this because we need to support offline usage of the website. More precisely, offline usage of an ArcGIS API for JavaScript webapp.

We are not using service workers instead of the ApplicationCache because supporting iOS is a critical requirement and service workers are not supported at all on iOS, on any browser.

The idea is that I'll manually call a function after the site is fully loaded that will dynamically create the text to be used for the new manifest. Then manually copy/paste it in the manifest file. So it's something I would only do when something in the site changes and the manifest file needs to be updated.

This tool, ManifestR, is very close: http://westciv.com/tools/manifestR/
but has two issues with it:

1- It does not handle image file URLs found in CSS files properly. For instance if it finds url(../images/myimage.png) it will add the relative link ../images/myimage.png directly in the manifest file instead of adding the non-relative link like www.mysite.com/images/myimage.png.

2- It does not list any of the scripts loaded through dojo.require (AMD modules).

I'm thinking of using similar code to fix these issues and compile the list of files. I already see how to fix #1, but can't figure out how to fix #2.

So, using JavaScript, how can I find the list of all script URLs used by the website, not just those loaded trough  tags (found in window.scripts object), but those loaded using AMD modules as well?

Basically I want to compile the same list that Chrome is showing me for the website in the Sources pane.

Ex:

[image]

I'm thinking that if this isn't available anywhere, maybe I could create a proxy function to dojo.require that keeps tracks of all files loaded through AMD.

But I wanted to ask here first, maybe I missed a tool of script that already does this? Or maybe my plan isn't good?

Thanks

Comment: I found that I can get the list of all loaded modules in require.modules

Comment: Even better, I found that I can get a list of all resources loaded via the Resource Timing API. First set the buffer size with performance.setResourceTimingBufferSize(some_value); then use window.performance.getEntriesByType('resource') to get the list of files. Much simpler.

Answer (score 1):

I've never used ApplicationCache for an ArcGIS API for JavaScript app, but I would recommend that you first serve up [a custom Dojo build of your application](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/guide/using-bower/index.html) in order to bundle your code into one or more build layers. If you configure your Dojo build properly (no small feat) you should know the exact scripts that will be required.

Also, I'd suspect that once you figure out how to get the list of scripts, you may have special considerations in order to get the Dojo AMD loader to be able to use the cached files. See: [dojo and the offline application cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5578382/dojo-and-the-offline-application-cache)

Good luck.

Comment: Yeah a coworker also suggested the same, create a custom bundle and only cache that in the application cache, instead of the whole list of modules and their dependencies. I'm thinking about it for later on, but right now it's not necessary as it's working with the complete list of files I got from the Resource Timing API. It works and I have other offline issues to deal with (like simulating some server request responses and caching the map tiles). As for loading the modules from the ApplicationCache, I did nothing, the browser already knows to get them from the cache if I'm offline. Thanks!